# How to make a spring in manim

Tags: python, manim

I am trying to make a spring that oscilates in manim

here is my try:

```py
from manim import *


class YoungModulus(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        # Set up the spring
        spring = always_redraw(lambda: ParametricFunction(
            lambda t: [t, np.sin(3*t), 0],
            t_range=[-4, 4],
            color=YELLOW
        ))

        # Set up the mass
        mass = Circle(
            radius=0.5,
            color=RED,
            fill_opacity=1,
            stroke_width=0
        )

        mass.move_to(spring.get_end())
        mass.add_updater(lambda m: mass.move_to(spring.get_end()))

        self.play(FadeIn(mass, spring))
        self.play(spring.animate.to_edge(RIGHT))
```

but I don't know how to make the right side stay still and only oscillate the right part as with the motion of a spring.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you were looking for somthing similar to this....

```
class UseParametricFunction(Scene):
def construct(self):
    vt = ValueTracker(0.5)
    graph = ParametricFunction(lambda u : np.array([0.05*u, 0.5*np.cos(u), 0.5*np.sin(u)]),
                               t_range=np.array([-4*TAU, 4*TAU, 0.1])).align_to(np.array([-4,0,0]), np.array([-1,0,0]))
    def changeLength(mob):
        i = vt.get_value()
        mob.become(ParametricFunction(lambda u : np.array([0.09*i*u, 0.5*np.cos(u), 0.5*np.sin(u)]),
                               t_range=np.array([-4*TAU, 4*TAU, 0.1])).align_to(np.array([-4,0,0]), np.array([-1,0,0])))

    graph.add_updater(changeLength)

    self.add(graph)
    for _ in range(4):
        self.play(vt.animate.set_value(2))
        self.play(vt.animate.set_value(0.5))
    return super().construct()
```